# How to use FFMPEG for a cutaway with audio crossfade?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to do a "cutaway" (change camera angles) using FFMPEG. I have HLS video from a left camera and a right camera. The start times are a little out of sync, so the left video actually started recording 4.21 seconds after the right video started recording. I'm trying to show the right video from the start to the 5 second mark and then cut over to the left video from its 0.79 second mark until the 5.79 second mark (which would have been the 5-10 second range on the right camera).

I realize these cuts probably fall on p-frames -- that's part of the test here. I want to see if FFMPEG will properly insert the necessary i-frame to make a smooth cut.

Finally, to get a smooth final product, I'm trying to do a 1-second audio crossfade during the transition (there's no need for any video fades).

I'm new at FFMPEG. I tried the following, but it didn't work. Anyone know what the correct command would have been?

```
ffmpeg -i right.m3u8 -ss 0 -t 5 -i left.m3u8 -ss 0.79 -t 5 -async 1 -filter_complex acrossfade=d=1:c1=exp:c2=exp mixed.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with a couple small tweaks to Mulvya's answer. You need to specify asetpts for the second file to make sure it starts at -0.5 second (-22050 samples). Also, I needed to get rid of the curves and just let it do linear curves on bother sides in order to maintain constant volume through the transition.

```
ffmpeg -i right.m3u8 -i left.m3u8 -filter_complex
   "[0]trim=duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vr];
    [1]trim=0.79:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vl];
    [0]atrim=duration=5.5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ar];
    [1]atrim=0.29:duration=5.5,asetpts=(PTS-STARTPTS - 22050)[al];
    [ar][al]acrossfade=d=1[a];
    [vr][vl]concat=n=2[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" mixed.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

If the videos don't overlap, neither will the audio streams, so there's no place for a crossfade. So, in this case, we'll have to use distinct trim filters to make this work.

```
ffmpeg -i right.m3u8 -i left.m3u8 -filter_complex \
       "[0]trim=duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vr]; \
        [1]trim=0.79:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vl]; \
        [0]atrim=duration=6,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ar]; \
        [1]atrim=0.79:duration=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[al]; \
        [ar][al]acrossfade=d=1:c1=exp:c2=exp[a]; \
        [vr][vl]concat=n=2[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" mixed.m3u8
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the videos DO overlap. The left camera for this test is 4.21 seconds behind the right camera recording. But the two videos from those markers on are synced. (I'm not able to try your command at the moment.)

Comment: I meant, in the sense of the timeline paradigm. You wish to cut from one video to another but the segments don't overlap, so the audios won't either.

Comment: Okay, now I follow what you're saying. Yes, the audio can only cross fade if there is audio to pull from both files for the entire duration of the cross fade. To clarify though, that is the case here. The first video extends for about 15 seconds after the cut point. The second video starts 0.79 seconds before the cut. The cross fade is 1-second in duration, so it should only need a half second of audio on either side of the video cut point. Unless I've misunderstood something.

Comment: The command you provided comes close, but instead of crossfading with overlap, I get a fade out and then a fade in. Tinkering now to see if I can fix it...

Comment: acrossfade by default is set to overlap. Experiment with the fade curves.

Comment: Got it working. 
 
     ffmpeg -i right.m3u8 -i left.m3u8 -filter_complex
        "[0]trim=duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vr];
         [1]trim=0.79:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vl];
         [0]atrim=duration=5.5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ar];
         [1]atrim=0.29:duration=5.5,asetpts=(PTS-STARTPTS - 22050)[al];
         [ar][al]acrossfade=d=1[a];
         [vr][vl]concat=n=2[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" mixed.m3u8